# Group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p \longrightarrow\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, denote by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the ring of $p-$adic integers.

Can we define a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p \longrightarrow\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: Yes, you can.$\ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a homomorphism, called the reduction modulo $p$, given by
$$
\sum_{i\ge 0}a_ip^i\mapsto a_0 \mod p.
$$
This is a standard definition, which is used among other things to show that the invertible elements in
the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$ consist of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}=\{\sum_{i\ge 0}a_ip^i \mid a_0\neq 0\}$.